# Get file extension when extension is not shown (Email msg attachments in outlook)

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, email-attachments, exchangewebservices, msg

I have a program that uses EWS to pull emails from an exchange server, gets the attachments off of them and converts them to PDFs.
Before I convert them, I check all of the extensions of the attachments to make sure they are something I can handle.

My problem is when an email (msg) is the attachment in an email. In outlook/exchange, these do not show the extension, so any way I try to pull the extension, I get nothing or something incorrect like .itemattachment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by loading the item attachment and the pulling the data from it. I put the data in html format then convert that to pdf.
I just do a check first to see if the type of attachment is file or item

Comment: I know that thread is old,...but what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an actual MSG file or an embedded message attachment? In the latter case there is no extension, or even a file name for that matter.

Comment: I'm not sure of the difference. It's an outlook email sent as an attachment in a new email

Comment: There is a pretty big difference - what is the content type of the attachment? You might want to post the whole MIME header of the attachment.